# Libgdx Sprite rotation around specific point

Tags: java, libgdx, sprites, box2d, rotation

I made complex dynamic body that rotates around other body that is static. It works perfectly, however I got messed up with sprite position on that body.
Here's what I have now
[image]

and here's what I need to have

[image]

I will add my code

```
private Body createSide(float x, float y, Sprite tmpSprite, boolean sharp){
      BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
      bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    if(!sharp){
        shape.setAsBox(1.8f / PPM, 0.2f / PPM);
    } else {
        shape.setAsBox(0.2f / PPM, 1.8f / PPM);
    }

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.shape = shape;

    bDef.position.set(x, y);
    Body body = world.createBody(bDef).createFixture(fdef).getBody();
    body.setAngularVelocity(-1f);
    tmpSprite.setPosition(bDef.position.x * 32, bDef.position.y * 32);
    return body;
}

private void createBody(int y, final int V_WIDTH){
        staticBody = createStaticBody(y, V_WIDTH);
        Body rightSide = createSide(5.5f, 15, sprites[0], true);
        Body leftSide = createSide(9.5f, 15, sprites[1], true);
        Body top = createSide(7.5f, 17, sprites[2], false);
        Body bottom = createSide(7.5f, 13, sprites[3], false);

        bodies[0] = rightSide;
        bodies[1] = leftSide;
        bodies[2] = top;
        bodies[3] = bottom;

...
...
...
    }
```

and here's my draw method

```
@Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb) {
        for (int i=0; i<bodies.length; i++){
            sprites[i].setRotation(bodies[i].getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
            sprites[i].draw(sb);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after 4 hours of searching finally I found the mistake. Problem was with the sprite origin. Here's the line that was necessary (staticBody is the body around other bodies will rotate)

```
tmpSprite.setOrigin(staticBody.getPosition().x / 32 + tmpSprite.getWidth() / 2,
                staticBody.getPosition().y / 32 + tmpSprite.getHeight() / 2);
```

And here's full code

```
private Body createSide(float x, float y, Sprite tmpSprite, boolean sharp){
        BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
        bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        if(!sharp){
            shape.setAsBox(1.8f / PPM, 0.2f / PPM);
        } else {
            shape.setAsBox(0.2f / PPM, 1.8f / PPM);
        }

        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        fdef.shape = shape;

        bDef.position.set(x, y);
        Body body = world.createBody(bDef).createFixture(fdef).getBody();
        body.setAngularVelocity(1f);
        //body.setFixedRotation(true);
        tmpSprite.setX(body.getPosition().x * 32 - tmpSprite.getWidth());
        tmpSprite.setY(body.getPosition().y * 32 - tmpSprite.getHeight());
        tmpSprite.setOrigin(staticBody.getPosition().x / 32 + tmpSprite.getWidth() / 2,
                staticBody.getPosition().y / 32 + tmpSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb) {
        for (int i=0; i<sprites.length; i++){
            float xball = 32 * (bodies[i].getPosition().x) - sprites[i].getWidth()/2;
            float yball = 32 * (bodies[i].getPosition().y) - sprites[i].getHeight()/2;
            sprites[i].setRotation(bodies[i].getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
            sprites[i].setPosition(xball, yball);
            sprites[i].draw(sb);
        }
    }
```